# The default value of PUB_HOSTED_URL FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL

Tags: flutter

I used to change the
PUB_HOSTED_URL,
FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL

Now I want to reset it to default. How I should do now?

Comment: Do you know what was the default value for `FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL `?

Answer (score 2):

Only delete the environment variables and run:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

And in your project folder:

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command in the terminal:

```
setx PUB_HOSTED_URL “https://pub.dartlang.org”
setx FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL “https://storage.googleapis.com”
```